# Hierarchial xml to Flat xml using XSLT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xslt, reporting-services

I have xml which is structed like following

```
<root>
  <PNode>
    <node1>
      <node1Child>data</node1Child>
      <node2Child>data</node2Child>
    </node1>
  </PNode>
  <SecondNode>
    <node1>
      <node1Child>
        <child>data</child>
      </node1Child>
    </node1>
  </SecondNode>
</root>
```

I want output using genric xslt because i have many xml to convert to this format.

```
<root>
  <Pnode-node1-node1Child>data</Pnode-node1-node1Child>
  <Pnode-node1-node2Child>data</Pnode-node1-node2Child>
  <SecondNode-node1-node1child-child>data</SecondNode-node1-node1child-child>
</root>
```

It could be more deep or less.
can I do it by XSLT pls give any example or reference

I want to do it to generate PDF from sql server 2k8 r2 rdl. because rdl do not accept nested xml so need to flatten it.

Comment: presume you mean <SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>data</SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. An extensive explanation is also provided. The transformation is robust and will work in case of namespaces and prefixed names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="pName"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="pName" select="concat($pName,name(),'-')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:param name="pName"/>
        <xsl:element name="{substring($pName,1,string-length($pName)-1)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <PNode-node1-node1Child>data</PNode-node1-node1Child>
    <PNode-node1-node2Child>data</PNode-node1-node2Child>
    <SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>data</SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>
</root>
```

**Update**: If there could be empy nodes...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="pName"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="pName" select="concat($pName,name(),'-')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:param name="pName"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$pName}{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Matching innermost element.

Comment: @Alejandro Hi Again, match="text()" ignores the empty tags, I need to include that also.  e.g if SecondNode-node1-node1child-child is empty this xlst will not include that in the final  xml. any tweak for that.

Answer (score 4):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vCompName">
   <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*[not(position() =last())]">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(), ':', '_')"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">-</xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:element name="{$vCompName}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <PNode>
        <node1>
            <node1Child>data</node1Child>
            <node2Child>data</node2Child>
        </node1>
    </PNode>
    <SecondNode>
        <node1>
            <node1Child>
                <child>data</child>
            </node1Child>
        </node1>
    </SecondNode>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <PNode-node1-node1Child>data</PNode-node1-node1Child>
   <PNode-node1-node2Child>data</PNode-node1-node2Child>
   <SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>data</SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Besides wrapping the document in a `root` top element, there is just a single template. It matches any non-whitespace-only text node.
2. The nodeset of all element-ancestors except the first one in document order (which is the last in the reverse axis `ancestor::`) are string-joined with a `'-'` character and an element is constructed with this string as a name.
3. Before the string-join operation in 2. above, every name is modified so that any `':'` character in it is substituted by an underline character. This makes the transformation not produce invalid compound names if there are namespace prefixes in some names.
4. Finally, the current text node is copied as a child of the dynamically-constructed element.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. BTW, why your `if test` expr is wrapped in an extra parenthesis?

Comment: @Flack: Thanks. As for the extra parenthesis: I started writing this as an C# `if` statement, then noticed what I am doing and put this inside a `test` attribute :). Will simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

Given this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <PNode>
        <node1>
            <node1Child>data</node1Child>
            <node2Child>data</node2Child>
        </node1>
    </PNode>
    <SecondNode>
        <node1>
            <node1Child>
                <child>data</child>
            </node1Child>
        </node1>
    </SecondNode>
</root>
```

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="flatten"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space(text())]" mode="flatten">
        <xsl:param name="name-prefix" select="''"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name">
            <xsl:call-template name="construct-name">
                <xsl:with-param name="name-prefix" select="$name-prefix"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="flatten">
            <xsl:with-param name="name-prefix" select="$name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space(text()))]" mode="flatten">
        <xsl:param name="name-prefix" select="''"/>

        <xsl:variable name="prefix">
            <xsl:call-template name="construct-name">
                <xsl:with-param name="name-prefix" select="$name-prefix"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="flatten">
            <xsl:with-param name="name-prefix" select="$prefix"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="construct-name">
        <xsl:param name="name-prefix"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$name-prefix">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($name-prefix, '-', local-name(.))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="flatten"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces wanted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <PNode-node1-node1Child>data</PNode-node1-node1Child>
    <PNode-node1-node2Child>data</PNode-node1-node2Child>
    <SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>data</SecondNode-node1-node1Child-child>
</root>
```

Comment: Hey alex its not working i tried in xml spy, stylus stuio and via c# code. its giving only data nodes are not coming at all. i just got datadatadata. Pls re-check it.

Comment: @Techmaster, specify your `XSLT  processor` please.

Comment: I am processing it using my code in C#. i Also tried using XML Spy tool. All are giving data only. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, test for a child node.

If there is a child node, pass it previous parameter value concatenated with the name of this element.

If there is only #text, output a new element using the parameter as its name, and set its contents to the #text

Comment: @Alex Nikolaenkov this is not giving me nodes. Output datadatadata

Comment: @Jagan, if you use browser to view the result use `View Source` to check xml document. I've verified my stylesheet with Xalan XSLT processor.